# Unable to retrieve textbox value and subtract from it

Tags: jquery

Ive a textbox with id fnlprce I want to retrieve its value on an event, subtract 50 from it and update it to the latest value, ive this piece of code to work over:

```
function updateDiscount() {
    var iniprce = parseInt($("#fnlprce").text());
    var fnlprce = iniprce-50;
    $("#dscntdprce").html("Price: " + fnlprce + ");
    $("fnlprce").html(fnlprce);
}
```

But something getting wrong as it is showing, ‘NaN’ in the output, guidance please :)

Comment: remove the last ' + "' from the 3rd line that gives a javascript error. However that would not explain your NaN output. What happens if you use val() instead of text() when retrieving the value?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code above.  You can see by the highlighting of the last two lines.

Comment: For money, you really should be using `parseFloat("1.99").toFixed(2);` with  instead of `parseInt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
var iniprce = parseInt($("#fnlprce").text());
```

to

```
var iniprce = parseInt($("#fnlprce").val());
```

because val() is current value of that textbox.

Besides that, change

```
$("#dscntdprce").html("Price: " + fnlprce + ");
```

to

```
$("#dscntdprce").html("Price: " + fnlprce);
```

because yours one have syntax error

Comment: Don't forget to pass the radix as second argument to `parseInt`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.val()` instead of `.text()` as an input's value is found in its `value=` attribute, and not as a text node inside of it.

```
function updateDiscount() {
    var iniprce = parseInt($("#fnlprce").val(), 10);
    var fnlprce = iniprce - 50;
    $("#dscntdprce").html("Price: " + fnlprce);
    $("#fnlprce").html(fnlprce);
}
```

Comment: huh, 4k? Good message for me :p

Comment: Thanks :) I have seen that, too :)